# How to denote the opposite case of the Kronecker Delta?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, power-series

The Kronecker delta is defined as [link to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta): 
$$\delta_{l,m} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }m=l,\\
0 & \text{if }m\neq l.
\end{cases}$$

I would like to denote the case where:
$$ = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }m=l,\\
1 & \text{if }m\neq l.
\end{cases}$$

How should this be done?

Comment: $1 - \delta_{m,l}$ is common.

Answer (score 16):

How about $1 - \delta_{l, m}$?

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility would be to use the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). For example, the Kronecker delta is $\delta_{l, m} = [l = m]$, while your "opposite case of the Kronecker delta" would just be $[l \neq m]$.